# Installing google cloud SDK

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

I am getting the following error while installing the google cloud SDK in WINDOWS.

SDK installation failed

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**step1:** Add C:\WINDOWS\system32 to path in both system variables and User variables in the environment variable.

**step2:** Run Comand prompt as admin and type "find". It should show `FIND: Parameter format not correct`

**step3:** Run Setup as ADMIN.
it should work

Answer (score 0):

This issue is generated since the command prompt needs to get the `'find.exe'` file location from your System's PATH environment variable; however, it is not being able to find it. Based on this, it is required to add the `"C:\WINDOWS\system32;"` string to the start of the **PATH** environment variable and to re-run the GoogleCloudSDKInstaller.exe file.

You can take a look on [this issue tracker ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/36260001) that was created to report this error message and that contains a full explanation about this **[Intended Behavior](https://issuetracker.google.com/36260001#comment4)**.